# gitlfs batch response: Post https://../info/lfs/objects/batch: ..proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I have a bitbucket server git repo with LFS turned on. Yesterday I activated the use of LFS for a number of file types in my local clone and pushed all changes, including .gitattributes in the repo root.

A colleague of mine pulled the changes, executed git LFS install but now finds in his clone the LFS link files instead of the real files.

Another git pull made no difference, and a git LFS pull gave him

```
$ git lfs pull
batch response: Post https://<bitbucket-server>/scm/<proj>/<repo>.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: 
...proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake  
error: failed to fetch some objects from 
'https://<bitbucket-server>/scm/<proj>/<repo>.git/info/lfs'
```

Unfortunately there is no hint on any git lfs info page what this means - and how to fix it.

Is there any way I can make git lfs work for the rest of the team?
And, just for curiosity, what is the reason for this message?
All git lfs tutorials pretend that it is easy to use git lfs, but obviously it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I can fix it by

> `unset https_proxy.`

git-lfs works with **http_proxy** fine. May be it's help some peoples in future! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `git lfs` operation is trying to use your corporate proxy server. You may have better luck if you set the `no_proxy` variable to ignore the `<bitbucket-server>` URL.

Typically it is set to something like this:

```
export no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost,.<your-domain>
```

But you can be explicit and set it to ignore `<bitbucket-server>`

```
export no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost,<bitbucket-server>
```

Please note the leading `.` before `<your-domain>` in that example.

Also by setting `GIT_TRACE=1` you can get more hints on what the problem might be.

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git lfs pull
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the `git-lfs` cannot work if you set proxy in your environment, so you can try to clean all your proxy, and then it maybe work.
You can check proxy setting by the following:
`env| grep -ai proxy`.